Knowledge distillation: ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 512 and 1000 for
This is the code:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16, ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.losses import KLDivergence
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

class DistillationLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, teacher_model, temperature=3.0, **kwargs):
        super(DistillationLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.teacher_model = teacher_model
        self.temperature = temperature
        self.kl_divergence = KLDivergence()

    def call(self, inputs, student_logits):
        teacher_logits = self.teacher_model(inputs, training=False)
        teacher_probs = tf.nn.softmax(teacher_logits / self.temperature, axis=-1)
        student_probs = tf.nn.softmax(student_logits / self.temperature, axis=-1)
        distillation_loss = self.kl_divergence(teacher_probs, student_probs)
        return distillation_loss

def build_student_model(base_model, num_classes):
    x = base_model.output
    x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)  # livello intermedio
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)  # deve avere la stessa dimensione dell'insegnante
    student_model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
    return student_model

def compile_model(model, teacher_model, temperature=3.0):
    distillation_layer = DistillationLayer(teacher_model, temperature)
    
    def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        student_logits = y_pred
        distillation_loss = distillation_layer(model.input, student_logits)
        student_loss = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, student_logits)
        return distillation_loss + student_loss
    
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  loss=custom_loss,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

def train_student_model(student_model, teacher_model, train_data, val_data, epochs=10):
    compile_model(student_model, teacher_model)
    student_model.fit(train_data,
                      validation_data=val_data,
                      epochs=epochs,
                      verbose=1)

def main():
    train_dir = 'dataset/imagenet-mini/train'
    val_dir = 'dataset/imagenet-mini/val'

    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.0)
    val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.0)

    train_data = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical'
    )

    val_data = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        val_dir,
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical'
    )

    num_classes = train_data.num_classes

    # Carica i modelli insegnanti senza il top
    vgg16 = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    resnet50 = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

    # Costruisci i modelli studenti
    student_vgg16 = build_student_model(vgg16, num_classes)
    student_resnet50 = build_student_model(resnet50, num_classes)

    # Addestra i modelli studenti
    print("Training with VGG16 as teacher")
    train_student_model(student_vgg16, vgg16, train_data, val_data)

    print("Training with ResNet50 as teacher")
    train_student_model(student_resnet50, resnet50, train_data, val_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This is the error:
Call arguments received by layer "distillation_layer" (type DistillationLayer):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32)
      • student_logits=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, 1000), dtype=float32)
I am trying to write a file for knowledge distillation of Resnet50, VGG16 and AlexNet model. In the following example I try to do it only for ResNet50 `your text` and VGG16.`

